# Overwriting 301 Redirect for specific pages

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I am moving an old domain to a new domain however some of the old pages are not available. Therefore pages that are still available on the new domain need to be redirected to the new existing page and all others need to be redirected to the overall domain. I am having the following redirect rules:

**Updated**

```
//Specific
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(title_1/?)$ https://www.website.com/$1
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(title_2/?)$ https://www.website.com/$1
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(title_3/?)$ https://www.website.com/$1
...

//Overall
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)$ https://www.website.com/blog
```

However the overall first rule overwrites all the other following rules which are made for the existing subpages. There are about 200 Subpages which are added to the htaccess. Also what I need to mention is that the overall website runs on domain.com/blog but all the subpages that are redirected are just domain.com/title_name_1.

I need the specified 200 pages to not be overwritten by the first rule. Thus not getting redirect to /blog.

I am kind of lost with this. Any help appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change order of your rules and better to use same directive `RedirectMatch` for all redirects:

```
//Example of Redirect for specific pages (about 200+) 
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(title_1|title_2|title_3)/?$ https://www.website.com/$1 

RedirectMatch 301 ^/(category/title_name_2/?)$ https://www.website.com/$1 

//Overall redirect for not specified pages in htaccess
RedirectMatch 301 ^ https://website.com/blog/
```

Make sure clear your browser cache or use a new browser for testing this change.

Comment: thanks for your help. This still does not work. It redirects all pages to /blog/page_title. However it should only redirect the specified pages to /blog/page_title all the other pages should just go to /blog without adding the page title. I did this ``RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)$ https://website.com/blog/ `` but it still overwrites all the other rules.

Comment: I updated it. Yes I used a different browser to test it.

Comment: Yes I think I found the mistake (title_1?) it needs to be (title_1/?)

Comment: ok try my updated rules again after completely clearing browser cache.

Comment: I updated it to the first version. Its working now. See my previous comment :) Thanks a lot!